# Mapserver Mount Error: Failed to resolve server ip.address.of.nas: Name or service not known

Tags: mapserver

I followed this guide to install mapserver on ubuntu: 
https://goworldwind.org/mapserver-and-data-installation/
, and when I set the step 3: Mount the MapServer Configuration and Data, I did

```
sudo mount ip.address.of.nas:name.of.vbox.share /data
```

There was an error:

```
Failed to resolve server ip.address.of.nas: Name or service not known
```

I used the VMware Workstation, anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace "ip.address.of.nas" and "name.of.vbox.share" with the ip address of your nas and the name of your vbox share. You also need to have a NAS device with the data on it. **"The data is available on a Network Attached Storage (NAS) device available from the World Wind team. These instructions assume that you have that device."** - says that page.

That page is not a guide for installing mapserver generally, its a guide for installing and setting up mapserver for the NASA worldWind data. If all you want to do is run mapserver, try the instructions from the main site:

http://mapserver.org/uk/index.html